# Help identify green insect with long antennae?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

This was found in south Texas, USA.
It size was around 3 centimetres without considering the antennas or legs.

[image]

Comment: No, not dangerous. I think they mostly can hop and fly, so move fairly quickly if disturbed, which might startle your daughter.

Comment: Nice strategy! Good to know that google lens identified it as a Katydid (Tettigoniidae) but I think that is not exactly the Speckled bush-cricket because it body size range is 10-15 mm (wikipedia) and the one I saw was bigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The green, narrow body suggests this is indeed a [katydid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tettigoniidae).

The red antennae, red eyes, and small, red-lined wings looks like the green form of a **[*Paracyrtophyllus robustus*](https://bugguide.net/node/view/93515) (Central Texas leaf katydid)** nymph.

[image]

<sup>Credit: Mike Quinn ; Source: [Bugguide.net](https://bugguide.net/node/view/399071)</sup>

[image]

<sup>Source: [Austin Bug Collection](http://www.austinbug.com/tettigoniidae.html)</sup>